# Browser "back" Button doesn't restart javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, anchor, reload

A similar question has already been asked, but im not at all happy with the solutions, which just can't be the only ones in such a simple case.

So I've got a page with a javascript animation. There are 4 images which are anchors, which link to new pages, and once you click on them, they grow to full size and it looks like they transform to the background, because the image is the background of the next page.

So here's my problem: When i click a link everything goes well, the Image grows to screen size and then the anchor triggers with a delay and links to the new page. But then, once i click on the "Back" button in the browser on the new page, i come back to a page where the screen is filled with the Image i've clicked, and only refreshing gets you out of it.

Is there any way to like reload the page when you come back to it through the "back" button in the Browser?

Comment: You click the link with an anchor where the url is the same? That means only the anchor changes. This never causes a page-refresh since changing the anchor is only a jump on the page itself. It wont refresh the page when you click back, too since the anchor is only removed. Because of this your onload-javascript is not executed again

Comment: The ancestors link to new pages, sorry i forgot to mention that in my question. Edited it now.

Comment: Firefox has a back/forward cache that stores the state of the *n* previously rendered documents (including the state of the Javascript engine). You might be hitting that cache. There are [ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/pageshow) to detect when that happens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've seen something that goes in this direction, but for it to work i would need to install an older version of jquery. That is really not what i want, and also i can't believe that there is no easier way to do this easy cool animation.. Its kind of unbelievable for me, cause i could swear i have such animations before.

Answer (score 0):

did you try putting the code in jQuery $(..) all the code in side the paranthesis!

Comment: As far as i know is $(handler) shorthand for $(document).ready(handler) and yes i have tried putting all my code in there.. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you can put some analogous code in jsfiddle and people will be able to help.